# How to efficiently copy the contents of a string into an array?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have a static string `"foo"` and a mutable array of sufficient length `let mut buf = [0u8; 16]`.

How can I most efficiently update the `buf` to contain the bytes of the string? I can iterate over the string as bytes with `.bytes()` and update the positions in the buffer one by one but it feels like there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `copy_from_slice`.

```rs
buf[..string.len()].copy_from_slice(string.as_bytes());
```

Another thing that's possibly useful is that you can make a byte slice with a string literal directly with `b`.

```rs
const SLICE: &[u8] = b"hello";
```

You can also make an array by dereferencing that.

```rs
const ARR: [u8; 5] = *b"hello";
```